# BottomNavigationBar with 5 items

Tags: flutter

When I try to create a BottomNavigationBar with 5 items, it errors out with:

> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..2, inclusive: 3

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new BottomNavDemo());
}

class BottomNavDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavDemoState createState() => new _BottomNavDemoState();
}

class _BottomNavDemoState extends State<BottomNavDemo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'my title',
      home: new Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                title: new Text('One'), 
                icon: new Icon(Icons.home)),
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                title: new Text('Two'),
                icon: new Icon(Icons.terrain)),
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                title: new Text('Three'),
                icon: new Icon(Icons.bluetooth)),
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                title: new Text('Four'),
                icon: new Icon(Icons.cake)),
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                title: new Text('Five'),
                icon: new Icon(Icons.edit)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It should be able to support 5 items in the list.  Correct?

Comment: I simply copy paste your code and it is working perfectly. Just try to clean your build or remove the app from the simulator or emulator and restart it.

Comment: @dhuma1981, I tried this on a new machine with a new installation of flutter and I get a blank white screen if I have 4 or 5 items.  If I comment two of them out so I only have 3 items, it comes up properly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Cleaning and restarting actually fixed the problem.
It also introduced a new problem.

Without explicitly setting

```
type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
```

The icons shows up white on a very light gray background which I couldn't even see until I clicked in the area where they were.  After setting this property, it is working properly.

Thanks to @dhuma1981 for your help.

Comment: I am happy to help you :)

Comment: You can accept your own answer to not have it shown as unanswered anymore.